# Как отключить автокомплит в sublime text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В settings - user выдаёт ошибку при "auto_complete": false (на скрине)

Comment: Запятую забыли после `true`. Пакет [**JSONComma**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSONComma) может правильно расставить запятые в JSON и JSON-подобных файлах за Вас. Спасибо.

Comment: используйте vs code он бесплатный и обходит sublime по всем пунктам.Я тоже перешел с sublime на него

Answer (score 1):

Нужно поставить запятую после true

Comment: комментарии к предыдущим ответам не стоит оформлять в виде нового ответа

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/492105)

Comment: @DaemonHK, в данном сообщении **содержится** решение вопроса.

Comment: @insolor еще бы помнить первоначальный ответ... Видимо я хотел указать про "лучше оставить комментарий, чем делать ответ", но промахнулся. Приношу извинения.

Comment: @DaemonHK, [первоначальный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1145541/revisions): "попробуй поставить запятую после true" - по сути я изменил только одно слово. Это вполне нормальный ответ, хотя и короткий.